# My template specialization differs debug version from release version, is this gcc bug?

Tags: c++, templates, symbols, specialization, weak

First of all, I've got a header file for a class, an specialization declaration without definition(code samples from internet)

$ cat foo.h

```
template<typename T>
class foo{
public:
  static void init(){
      return;
  }

};

template<>  void foo<int>::init();
```

Then there're 2 implementation files for template specialization

```
$ cat foo_int.cpp 
#include "foo.h"
#include<stdio.h>
template<>
void foo<int>::init(){
    printf("init int foo\n");
}

$ cat foo_float.cpp 
#include "foo.h"
#include<stdio.h>
template<>
void foo<float>::init(){
    printf("init float foo\n");
}
```

Finally I got a main file

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include "foo.h"

int main(){
  foo<int>::init();
  foo<float>::init();
}
```

If I compile it without optimization and run it, it gives:

> g++ foo_int.cpp foo_float.cpp main.cpp && a.out
> init int foo
> init float foo

If I add optimization, then the result is different:

> $ g++ foo_int.cpp foo_float.cpp main.cpp -O2 && a.out
> init int foo

The result is different. Some explanation from internet said this is due to some internal mechanism of "weak symbol" in gcc implementation, but my question:

> 1. Is "weak symbol"/"strong symbol" a concept of gcc/g++, or it's part of the c/c++ language specification.
> 2. If debug and release results are different, should I say this is a bug/issue of gcc/g++, in regard with "weak symbol" mechanism? As a developer, I wouldn't expect my debug version to behave differently from release version.

I tried clang, unfortunately same error. Is this an "acceptable" case for C/C++ that debug/release "should" behave so differently?

Comment: Declaration of specialization of `void foo<float>::init()` is not visible in `main`... Your program is ill formed.

Comment: Be careful when formatting the text. Only code blocks preserve white spaces and line breaks. When you pasted the `g++` console output under the `>` markup, it ignored line breaks all got squashed in to a one line of text. To preserve line breaks, put a double-space at the end of each line. Or just paste is as a code block. Readers usually have no problems in noticing which one contains code and which one contains console dump :)

Comment: "I've got a header file for a class" -- no, you've got a header file for a **template**.

Comment: declare the header of the explicit instantiation in the header file or use `extern template`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've violated the *one definition rule* — your program contains *two* definitions of `foo<float>::init`.

One definition occurs in the compilation unit `foo_float.cpp`, and the other appears in the compilation unit `main.cpp`.

Violating the one definition rule means undefined behavior — in this case, what likely happens is:

- With optimizations off, the program generates an actual function call, and the linker happened to put `foo_float.cpp`'s version of the function in the executable.
- With optimizations on, when compiling `main.cpp` the compiler inlined the function — naturally, it would inline `main.cpp`'s version of the function.

Comment: In main.cpp: because there is no `foo<float>::init` specialization declaration, then the general one is considered definition for `foo<float>::init`? Is this the reason?

Answer (score 6):

The language definition requires that you declare an explicit specialization before it is used:

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is
>   explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared
>   before the first use of that specialization that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in
>   which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required. [temp.expl.spec]/6.

There is no declaration of the explicit specialization of `foo<float>::init()` at the point where it is called from `main`, but there is an explicit specialization in `foo_float.cpp`, so the behavior of the program is undefined.